# displaying a date after specific number days by reading a number

Tags: shell-script, date

I have a file in which there is a line:

```
Password=md@2507
```

where 2507 is the date when I changed the password for the last time. I want a script that reads the date from the Password line of that file and then shows me the date after 10 days as this password will expire after 10 days of this date.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sed` and GNU `date`:

```
sed -En 's#^Password=.*@([0-9]{2})([0-9]){2}$#date -d "\2/\1 +10 days" +%F#ep'
```

We turn the 2507 to 07/25 as GNU `date` expects dates in the US style. However note that 07/25 is understood as the 25th of July ***of the current year***.

What that means is that if you run that command on 2017-01-02 on a `Password=x@2712` input, you'll get a `2018-01-06` output (10 days after the 27th of December ***2017***).

What you could do instead is:

```
eval "$(date +'d=%d m=%m y=%Y')"
awk -v "y=$y" -v "today=-$m-$d" -F @ '
  /^Password=.*@[0-9]{4}$/ {
    d = "-" substr($NF, 3) "-" substr($NF, 1, 2)
    d = (d > today ? y - 1 : y) d
    system("date -d \"" d " +10 days\" +%F");
  }'
```

In `eval "$(date +'d=%d m=%m y=%Y')"`, we get date to output the current date in `d=25 m=07 y=2016` format. We take that and evaluate it as shell code so as to set the `$d`, `$m` and `$y` shell variables. It's better than doing `d=$(date +%d) m=$(date +%m) y=$(date +%Y)` as it runs only one `date` command and avoids the problem when that command is run at 23:59:59.9 on the last day of the month.

Then we run `awk`, with the `y` awk variable set to the content of the `$y` shell variable (`2017`) and `today` set to `-01-02`.

In `awk`, if the current record matches the `^Password=.*@[0-9]{4}$` regular expression. That is if it starts with `Password=` and ends in `@` followed by 4 decimal digits, then we:

- Extract the date in those last 4 digits and store it in the `d` variable as `-mm-dd` like for `today`.
- If `d` is lexically greater than `today`, for instance in our example above `-12-27` is greater than `-01-02`, then we set `d` to the year before (`2016-12-27`), and to the current year otherwise.
- Then we run the `date -d "2016-12-27 +10 days" +%F` command. Assuming GNU `date` that means printing in `%F` format (that is `YYYY-MM-DD`) the date as specified by `2016-12-27 +10 days`, that is 10 days after 2016-12-27.

Comment: You can avoid **GNU* sed* if use `date -f <(sed …`

Comment: `date` can be simplyfied by `10 day` instead `+10 days`

Comment: Thank u very much Mr. Stephane. Its very helpful for me. i m very new to Linux scripting. Can u please explain this whole command, i mean what each command does.